# What are the mElement options for AudioObjectPropertyAddress objects?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, audio, sdk

In the MacOS SDK, an AudioObjectPropertyAddress may be defined as below:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress pa;
pa.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar;
pa.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;
pa.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
```

I'm primarily interested in the mElement property. What are the values to which this property can be set and what are their different use cases?

Secondarily, I understand that the options for mScope are "kAudioDevicePropertyScope"Output, "..."Input and "..."Global. Is the global to be used when you're not sure if you should just input or output?

Any knowledge or documentation here would be very useful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the documentation is in the header files. Specifically you'd want to look at `CoreAudio/AudioHardware.h`, to see which elements are supported by each object.

Here is a snippet of the doc for the Audio System Object:

```
/*!
    @enum           AudioSystemObject Properties
    @abstract       AudioObjectPropertySelector values provided by the AudioSystemObject class.
    @discussion     The AudioSystemObject class is a subclass of the AudioObject class. the class
                    has just the global scope, kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, and only a master element.
...
```

So, this audio object has only a **master element**.

For more info on the scope, look into `CoreAudio/AudioHardwareBase.h`:

```
/*!
    @enum           Property Address Constants
    @abstract       The valid values for the scope in a property address.
    @constant       kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal
                        The AudioObjectPropertyScope for properties that apply to the object as a
                        whole. All objects have a global scope and for most it is their only scope.
    @constant       kAudioObjectPropertyScopeInput
                        The AudioObjectPropertyScope for properties that apply to the input side of
                        an object.
    @constant       kAudioObjectPropertyScopeOutput
                        The AudioObjectPropertyScope for properties that apply to the output side of
                        an object.
    @constant       kAudioObjectPropertyScopePlayThrough
                        The AudioObjectPropertyScope for properties that apply to the play through
                        side of an object.
```

Hope this is still useful for you.